# Receiving data in Node.js in chunks - when is the transmission finished?

Tags: node.js, sockets, puppeteer

I have two processes that are talking to each other - the client is a C# console app.  The server is a Node.js app which is utilizing the 'net' module (TCP).

The process I need to complete is:

1. The C# client connects to the Node.js server and sends HTML.
2. The Node.js receives the HTML data, and produces a PDF (using Puppeteer).
3. The Node.js server sends the PDF to the C# client as a byte array.

This is working smoothly **until** the payload in step 1 reaches a certain size.  At that point, the data starts to get split into multiple chunks.  The combined size of the chunks is equal to the payload that was originally sent, so it's all arriving at the server.

This causes a problem because the code to produce the PDF is in the `socket.on(data)` event.  Since data is received multiple times, the server is creating multiple PDFs, and none of them are complete.

Some of the posts I've read have suggested utilizing the `socket.on(end)` event, but that event isn't firing because the connection isn't being closed - I need to keep the connection open so I can execute step 3.

My first thought was "I need to increase the buffer sizes so the entire file is sent," but after doing some research, I've decided against this since it appears that splitting the data is expected behavior.

My question is: how can I tell when the entire payload has arrived at the Node.js server?

- Is there a socket event or another event in Node.js I could utilize?
- Is there a property on the `data` object sent I could examine?
- Is there a way for the client to "signal" that it has finished sending data?

It seems like this must be a common scenario, so I'm looking for some best practices since I'm relatively new to Node.js.

**UPDATE**

Here is the (abbreviated) code that causes multiple PDFs to be created because data is being received multiple times:

```
const net = require('net');
const PORT = 8080;
const ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1';

const server = net.createServer(onConnectionOpen);
server.listen(PORT, ADDRESS);

function onConnectionOpen(socket) {
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        const folderName = 'reports';
        var fileName = functions.getRandomString(50) + '.pdf';
        var fullPath = process.cwd() + '\\' + folderName + '\\' + fileName;

    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setContent(data.toString());
        const pdf = await page.pdf({ path: fullPath, format: 'Letter' });

        console.log('Total bytes returned: ' + pdf.length);
        socket.write(pdf);

        await browser.close();
    })();
})

socket.on('end', () => {
    socket.destroy();
})
```

}

I've tried moving the Puppeteer and the `socket.write(...)` to the `socket.on('end')`, but that code doesn't run after the PDF is generated because the connection is still open.

Comment: We could help a lot better if you showed your actual node.js code for receiving the data.

Comment: Data beyond a certain size will likely arrive in chunks.  You have to be able to detect when the last chunk has arrived somehow.  If there's some reason you can't use the `end` event (which I still don't understand why and is the usual way to know when a stream is done sending you data), then you have to devise some other way in how you send the data to know when the last chunk has arrived (perhaps sending some delimiter that you can watch for).  That would be on you to do that.

Comment: I've updated with the code sample.

The reason I can't use the end event is because according to my testing and what I've read on nodejs.org, the end event fires when the connection is closed.  I'm keeping the connection open because after the node.js service receives the data, it needs to send data back on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Append the data of any single chunk received in the socket.on(data) handler up to the chunk that matches the condition data.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("");

If the payload is html it should work. You simply have a delimiter at the end of your payload and you use it.

Comment: data.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("</html>");

Comment: That might be the solution I end up going with, but... it is specific to my scenario.  There must be a better way to handle this scenario for others (non-HTML) who are sending data to a Node.js service, and receiving a response back from the Node.js service.

Comment: I think you must use a different termination string for each scenario. Anyway if you find a general solution let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

If the sender isn't going to close the socket when it's done sending, then you have to tell when it's done sending by reading something in the data.  There are lots of ways to do that.  For example, you could encode it as a MIME part which has unique markers at the beginning and end of it that you can watch for while reading.

Since you've said the content is HTML that you control the sending of on the other end, you could just use an ending `</html>` at the end of the HTML as a delimiter.  To do this the simple way, you'd have to make sure there aren't any embedded HTML documents in the main one (like iframes with local content).  If you can make those assumptions, then you can use the detection of that `</html>` as a delimiter to tell you when you're done receiving the HTML.

With these simplifying assumptions, you can detect that like this:

```
const net = require('net');
const PORT = 8080;
const ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const server = net.createServer(onConnectionOpen);
server.listen(PORT, ADDRESS);

function onConnectionOpen(socket) {
    let receivedData = "";
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        receivedData += data.toString();
        // if we have the ending tag of our HTML, then process it
        let html = receivedData;
        if (html.indexOf("</html>") !== -1) {
            // reset receivedData so if any more data arrives (after the </html>)
            // it won't affect the html string we now have locally
            receivedData = "";
            const folderName = 'reports';
            const fileName = functions.getRandomString(50) + '.pdf';
            const fullPath = process.cwd() + '\\' + folderName + '\\' + fileName;

            (async () => {
                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

                const page = await browser.newPage();

                await page.setContent(html);
                const pdf = await page.pdf({ path: fullPath, format: 'Letter' });

                console.log('Total bytes returned: ' + pdf.length);
                socket.write(pdf);

                await browser.close();
            })().catch(err => {
                // handle error here
            });
        }
    });

    socket.on('end', () => {
        socket.destroy();
    });  
}
```

If there can be embedded HTML documents, then it takes a little more code to know when you've got the outer `</html>`.  And, if you can't be sure the `</html>` will be lowercase, you have to do a case insensitive search too.

If you can't even guarantee there will be a `</html>` at the end of the HTML content, then you need to somehow ensure there is some known delimiter at the end or you have to first send the length of the content so you know when you've got all the data.  There's just no other way to know where the end of the content is.

Comment: I'll look into the MIME encoding, but at the very least, I can always append each message with something like </EOF> and check on the service end for that string.

However, this experience has me wondering how other TCP services deal with this scenario.  A service receiving a message and sending a reply only after the entire message has been received seems like a common scenario (for example, you send a query to SQL Server and get a response back).  How do these services handle this?

Comment: Also, if I decided to close the connection when the client is done sending, is there a way to utilize socket.on(end)?  Is there a way for the node.js service to re-open the connection, even though it was opened initially by the client?

Comment: @ChadSC - They use a network data format that makes it clear where the data ends.  That's what you have to do too.  You can send the data length ahead of time or you can add a known delimiter that isn't likely to occur in the real content.

Comment: @ChadSC - No.  You can't reopen a connection that has already been closed.  The client would have to send another request to get the response.  FYI, if your server was an HTTP server instead of a regular TCP server, the request/response part of the whole thing is built into that protocol so the HTTP client and server code would manage that for you.  You would post the data to the server and then send a response after receiving it.  HTTP would either use the content-length header or MIME markers to know where the end of the content was.